# perl "for" loop to get status of the service

Tags: perl

I have a perl script where it will start the service and checks for the status of the service.
But when I start the service the application will take 15 seconds to change the service status from "No" to "Yes" and my perl script returns status as "No" because it checks the status immediately after I start the service.
So, I want a "for" loop for my perl script where it should checks for the status for every 1 second and breaks the for loop once it gets the status as "Yes" and should exit after 15 seconds.

```
sub trim($)
{
    $string = shift;
    $string =~ s/^\s+//;
    $string =~ s/\s+$//;
    return $string;
}
$connectstatus = trim(`AppStatus.sh | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<Status>)[^<]+"``);
```

The above command in my perl script will return the status immediately after I start the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a `for` loop, you want a `while` loop.

```
while (`AppStatus.sh | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<Status>)[^<]+"` eq 'No') {
  # do nothing
}
```

Which can be simplified to:

```
1 while `AppStatus.sh | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<Status>)[^<]+"` eq 'No';
```

But I'm not sure that's what you really want to do. What if the service doesn't start up successfully? You status check will always return "No" and your program will be stuck in an infinite loop.

Instead, why not put a `sleep` command in, so your program waits 15 seconds before checking the service status?

**Update:** Something like this, perhaps...

```
my $stop_checking = time + 15;
my $app_status = 'No';

while (time < $stop_checking and $app_status = 'No') {
  sleep 1;
  $app_status = `AppStatus.sh | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<Status>)[^<]+"`;
}

if ($app_status eq 'No') {
  # After 15 seconds, the service still hadn't started
} else {
  # Everything is ok
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that's why I wanted a for loop where it should check for the status for max 15 seconds and returns whatever the output comes after 15 seconds and exit the for loop. Suppose if I get the "Yes" status at 8th second then the for loop should exit at that time.

Comment: @charan: Maybe put a `sleep 1` in the `while` loop so you're not constantly hammering the service status checker.

Comment: I didn't get what you are telling on your last reply to include sleep 1

Comment: @charan: The while loop will execute quickly. You'll be calling your server status checker many times a second. And you really don't need to get the correct answer that quickly. So just checking once a second will be sufficient. You can do that by adding `sleep 1` inside the `while` loop.

Comment: Oh great, Can you tell me how do I do that and if possible can I include the same in bash script as well.

Comment: @charan: I thought I did :-) But I've now added it to my sample code.